# Cannot Upgrade jailbroken iPod touch 4.3.3 to iOS 6.1.2

Tags: ipod-touch, jailbreak, restore, software-update

I got a jailbroken iPod from a friend and I want to update to iOS 6 so I can restore my backed up data on it.

I tried SHIFT + Restore / Upgrade to iOS 6 but the first error I got was this

[image: Before using TinyUmbrella] **Figure 1**

Then I did some research and ended up getting **TinyUmbrella** and doing the hosts redirection and **SHSH** trick. After that I repeated the restore process now I'm getting this error (**Figure 2**) in the second phase of ***Verifying Update iPod update with Apple*** (**Figure 3**)

[image: After using TinyUmbrella]**Figure 2**

[image]**Figure 3**

PS: I also tried DFU mode but I got error **1600**.

Can you please help me restore or update my iPod to **any** OFW. My goal is to **remove** the CFW.

Comment: You shouldn't have to use tinyUmbrella to restore to the official, current firmware version. What happens when you click restore in iTunes without holding shift?

Comment: @ChrisA I was getting error 1394 like I said in the post. I think it had to do with the fact that it was 6.0 not 6.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved this. It turns out I had 6.0 (I didn't know because my friend was the one who got it and Apple isn't signing it anymore). I downloaded 6.1.2 and then my IP got blocked for too many requests. So I used a VPN for verification and then it worked.

So, like [@Chris A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/31423/chris-a) said; You don't need to do all that TinyUmbrella crap (unless you're downgrading). If you have the current iOS offline (like in my case) or updating to the recent firmware, it'll work just fine.

Thanks to all that **stared** at my question.